# How to display the referenced page？

Tags: citing, jabref

I quoted a few pages of a book, pages 20-23， I use JabRef reference manager，How can I display the referenced page？

Comment: What do you mean? Does this have anything to do with TeX?

Comment: I guess you want something like `\cite[pages 20-23]{bookkey}`  with `bookkey` is the key of the bib entry in your bib file ...

Comment: Yes ，it is just I need. thank you very much